# How to solve "Service Fabric Partition is in error" error?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

I installed service fabric locally and set up five cluster node. I followed  [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app#) and downloaded source code from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-quickstart/). It worked fine. Now I created one .net core application (docker enabled) API with visual studio 2019. I published image on docker hub (I ran image locally to confirm it is working fine.). Then I create service fabric project through visual studio and add container to it. I published on local cluster of five nodes. First one is already running. It is build and published successfully. But on service fabric explorer, it is showing me this error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Did you [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-debug-windows-containers) your machine to run SF containers?

Comment: Yes.I first tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app. It worked fine. All five node of cluster are healthy. Then I try to deploy docker container. Facing this issue now.

Comment: what do you see if you click on the faulty partition?

Comment: You can see in the image.

Comment: "download is in error. Deployment is  not supported for this type of node. " something like that.